# PHP: Determine a time diff's largest interval - minutes, hours, days, weeks, etc

Tags: php, time, diff

After calculating a time difference, how can I determine if the diff is only minutes, or is it hours, or days, weeks, months, years...?

```
$now = new DateTime('now');
$expire_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+ 3 weeks'));
$expire_on = new DateTime($expire_date);
$time_left = $now->diff($expires_on);

*** pseudo code below showing what I am trying to do
if ($time_left < 1 hour)
   display just minutes
elseif ($time_left < 1 day)
   display hours & minutes
elseif ($time_left < 1 week)
   display days, hours & minutes
elseif ($time_left < 1 month)
   display weeks, days, hours & minutes
elseif ($time_left < 1 year)
   display months, weeks, days, hours & minutes
endif
** end pseudo code
```

As I quickly learned, I need to clarify the question.  I want to display ONLY the bare minimum info. For example:  "39 minutes remaining" and not "0 days, 0 hours, 39 minutes remaining".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php - there are properties in the DateInterval object (of which $time_left is one) for most of those, so you can test them and see if they're above 0. I suggest starting with the largest.

For example:

```
$now = new DateTime('now');
$expire_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+3 weeks'));
$expire_on = new DateTime($expire_date);
$time_left = $now->diff($expire_on);

echo format_interval($time_left);

function format_interval($time_left) {
    $format_string = "";
    $weeks = (int) ($time_left->d / 7);
    $days = (int) ($time_left->d - ($weeks * 7));
    if ($time_left->y > 0) $format_string = "%y year(s), %m month(s), $weeks week(s), $days day(s), %h hour(s) and %i minute(s)";
    elseif ($time_left->m > 0) $format_string = "%m month(s), $weeks week(s), $days day(s), %h hour(s) and %i minute(s)";
    elseif ($weeks > 0) $format_string = "$weeks week(s), $days day(s), %h hour(s) and %i minute(s)";
    elseif ($time_left->d > 0) $format_string = "$days day(s), %h hour(s) and %i minute(s)";
    elseif ($time_left->h > 0) $format_string = "%h hour(s) and %i minute(s)";
    elseif ($time_left->i > 0) $format_string = "%i minute(s)";
    else $format_string = "%s second(s)";
    return $time_left->format($format_string);
}
```

Live demo: https://3v4l.org/BiYHD . Try adjusting the `$expire_date` and test the results you get.

N.B. The DateInterval class doesn't support telling you the number of weeks, for some reason. Above I've assumed that dividing the number of days by 7 is sufficient to calculate that. You then have to recalculate the remaining days (once the days in the allocated weeks are subtracted).

Comment: I tested a 4 month expiration date and got something informative:     "3 month(s), 4 week(s), 1 day(s), 23 hour(s) and 59 minute(s)" .  I presume it is accurate in that the 4 weeks is not a month, and the curious  result came from the NOW clock starting ticking immediately in running my code - it very quickly ticked down to a few seconds less than 4 months.   Thanks for your help!

Comment: Very close solution. While testing, I got a result:  3 week(s), 0 day(s), 23 hour(s) and 59 minute(s).  Would be nice to not display anything with a zero. As I mentioned, I will be looking at your code and maybe DIY it, but a quick fix is always appreciated...  Thanks again.

Comment: A quick ternary operator should sort you out with the zeroes issue

Comment: I'm flattered that you think I know what a "ternary operator" is.  No worries. Prof. Google can tell me, I am sure.

Comment: It certainly can, as can the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) . It's like an `if` statement, except you can embed it into other statements - e.g. you can concatenate it into string. For example I was thinking you could use it to check if a certain value was 0, and if so, skip that bit of the output. Here's one example: `elseif ($time_left->m > 0) $format_string = "%m month(s), ".($weeks == 0 ? "" : $weeks."week(s),")." $days day(s), %h hour(s) and %i minute(s)";`